# Por que minha conexão com o banco de dados não está dando certo? PHP orientado a objetos

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados, orientação-a-objetos

```
<?php 
<?php 
class getForm{ 
    public $nome; 
    public $email;
    public $tel; 
    public $query;
    public $conexao = null;
    public $usuario = "root";
    public $senha = "";
    public $banco = "testando";
    public $servidor = "localhost";

    public function getNome(){ 
        $this->nome = $_POST['nome']; 
    } 

    public function getEmail(){ 
        $this->email = $_POST['email']; 
    } 

    public function getTel(){ 
        $this->tel = $_POST['tel']; 
    } 
}
if (isset($_POST['submit']))  {

    echo "<span style='color:green;'>Enviado com sucesso!</span>";
    function setConexao(){
        $this->conexao = mysqli_connect($this->servidor, $this->usuario, $this->senha, $this->banco);
        if($this->conexao)
        {
            echo "DEU";
        }
        else {
            echo "Falha na conexao com o Banco de Dados!<br />";
            echo "Erro: " . mysql_error();
            die();
        }
    }
    function setusuario(){

        $query = mysqli_query($this->conexao, "INSERT INTO contato
        VALUES ('$this->nome','$this->tel','$this->email')");
        echo "conectado";

    }

}
?>
```

Comment: Qual a mensagem de erro que aparece?

Comment: Na verdade não aparece mensagem de erro, simplesmente não conecta, não aparece nenhuma mensagem que era para aparecer (somente a de Enviado com sucesso!), nem a de erro q eu coloquei, por isso eu queria saber se tem alguma coisa de errado.

Comment: Tenta encapsular o mysqli_connect em um try catch e ver se pega alguma exceção.

Comment: function setConexao(){
  
try {
    $this->conexao = mysqli_connect($this->servidor, $this->usuario, $this->senha, $this->banco);
} catch( Exception $e ) {

    echo $e->getCode();
}
}
Eu usei assim e não tá mostrando nenhuma mensagem mesmo assim

Comment: Alguem please me ajuda, eu tenho que fazer isso p conseguir minha vaga no estágio e eu tenho q entregar logo p meu supervisor

Comment: @Rebeca a conexão está dentro da função "setConexao()", onde você está chamando ela? no seu código, não acontece nada porque a função não está sendo chamada

Comment: e onde e como eu chamo ela?

Answer (score 1):

```
class getForm{ 
    public $nome; 
    public $email;
    public $tel; 
    public $query;
    public $conexao = null;
    public $usuario = "root";
    public $senha = "";
    public $banco = "testando";
    public $servidor = "localhost";

    public function getNome($nome){ 
        $this->nome = $nome;
    } 

    public function getEmail($email){ 
        $this->email = $email;
    } 

    public function getTel($tel){ 
        $this->tel = $tel;
    }

    public function setConexao(){
        $this->conexao = mysqli_connect($this->servidor, $this->usuario, $this->senha, $this->banco);
        if(!$this->conexao){
            echo "Falha na conexao com o Banco de Dados!<br />";
            echo "Erro: " . mysql_error();
            die();
        }
    }

    public function setUsuario(){       
        $query = mysqli_query($this->conexao, "INSERT INTO contato
        VALUES ('$this->nome','$this->tel','$this->email')");
        echo "conectado";

    }
}
```

Primeiramente você cirou uma classe e precisa instanciá-la, no seu caso, as operações ocorrerão quando houver o submit do formulário, então vamos realizar as operações dentro do `if(isset($_POST['submit']))`.

As funções de conexão e definição de usuário podem ser parte da classe principal, não precisam estar dentro do `if()`, sendo assim, você poderá acessar essas funções de qualquer outra parte do código em que a classe esteja instanciada.

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']))  {
    /*
        Aqui nós instanciamos a classe
    */

    $getForm = new getForm();

    /*
        Agora teremos acesso as funções da sua classe, assim poderemos verificar a existencia dos dados necessários para a utilização das mesmas
        Após verificar a existencia e o preenchimento dos campos, chamamos as funções da classe responsáveis por definirem as variáveis que serão inseridas no banco de dados
        OBS: Veja que aterei as funções para facilitar a verificação e tratamento das variáveis antes de enviá-las ao banco de dados, evitando SQL Injections e outros possiveis problemas
    */

    if((isset($_POST['nome'])) && (!empty($_POST['nome']))){
        // fazer tratamento das variáveis antes de enviá-las ao banco de dados
        $getForm->getNome($_POST['nome']);
    }
    if((isset($_POST['email'])) && (!empty($_POST['email']))){
        // fazer tratamento das variáveis antes de enviá-las ao banco de dados
        $getForm->getEmail($_POST['email']);
    }
    if((isset($_POST['tel'])) && (!empty($_POST['tel']))){
        // fazer tratamento das variáveis antes de enviá-las ao banco de dados
        $getForm->getTel($_POST['tel']);
    }

    /*
        Agora podemos chamar as funções de conexão e envio dos dados
    */

    $getForm->setConexao();
    $getForm->setUsuario();

    echo "<span style='color:green;'>Enviado com sucesso!</span>";    
}
```

> [Tratamento de Formulários PHP](http://www.codigomaster.com.br/desenvolvimento/tratamento-de-dados-formularios-php)
>
> [Referência da função **FILTER_INPUT()**](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.filter-input.php)
>
> [Referência de exemplos de Expressões Regulares PHP](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/regex.examples.php)
>
> **Sugiro a leitura da [documentação PHP](https://secure.php.net/docs.php) e pesquisas sobre tratamento de formulários e variáveis**